# Azure VIP swap takes more than a minute

Tags: azure

....and the site doesn't respond in that time at all. Some responses even fail.

This is giving a horrible user experience where the site suddenly stops reacting for the people that are online at that moment.

**The site is completely warmed up** and responsive through the temporarily url.

Here is the log:
[image: VIP swap taking 1 minute and 18 seconds]

- Is there anything to speed this up?
- Is this normal behaviour or is this an error that should be reported?

Comment: why this auto-scale ? Do you by chance use only one instance ?

Comment: I have one to three instances running. To be honest I can't remember at this specific point, but it could that one instance was running. I'm relatively sure 'long' downtimes of more than 30 seconds also happen when I have two or three instances running. But why would this matter for a VIP swap?

Comment: frankly it should not matter. But it would probably matter if your slots have different instance counts. So, just for the sake of trial, make both slots with  2 instances (minimum), both slots equal number of instances and test the swap. I personally would expect downtime of up to 1 minute.

Comment: For me that defeats a bit the purpose of a VIP swap. One minute downtime makes it impossible to put a new version live while there are users on the platform - it's a horrible user experience. I've tried this question on multiple channels of Microsoft, but I never get a real answer to it. I really don't get this. They should at least be able to tell if it's expected behaviour or not and communicate that clearly.

Comment: unfortunatelly you have right. But if you only do Web, why not take a look at Web Apps. In stadanrd tier you have up to 5 deployment slots (incl. prod), you can name those slots, you can assign custom domains to those slots, you can directly integrate with Source control each of the slots, and I do believe there the swap is without downtime.

Comment: You are paying MS for this: They are pretty good with customer service, so I would ask them.

Answer (score 0):

From the log you posted it seems that the operation that consumes a long time is "ChangeDeploymentConfigurationBySlot".
An azure configuration change by default triggers the restart of the role instance (which might explain why your clients are experiencing downtime).
You can get further details in this blog: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/handling-cloud-service-role-configuration-changes-in-windows-azure/